# Filtering a listview having a custom adapter with multiple parameters

Tags: android, listview, filter, custom-adapter

I have a listview with shows houses for rent based on a locality. The app provides a filter option to filter the listview elements based on some parameters such as rent, number of room, and type of furnishing. My basic plan to filter the elements is by searching through the three parameters for each element in the listview, and if the filter for that particular element is requested by the user, then the element is displayed. But, this seems like a long process. Is there a better way for filtering elements having multiple parameters using a custom adapter?

Comment: Better start using [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for your custom adapter

Comment: what adapter are you using? where does your data come from?